# How to access to data inside a document

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How can I access to data inside a document when inside that document is a subcollection and the data field I want?. For example I would like to access to the field "name"

[image]

I've already tried this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Rooms')
        .doc('8w0TE4D04xyeGgL3xAyk') //ID from specific room (RoomA,RoomB...)
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) => {
          querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
            print(doc["name"]);
          });
        });
```

This is the error that gives me in console:

> error: The argument type 'Set Function(QuerySnapshot)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr Function(DocumentSnapshot)'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [proyectoihc2] lib\database.dart:66)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you're doing wrong,

- This isn't javaScript, the way you use arrow syntax is different,

Either do this

```
(value){
...
}
```

or use this if your function has only one line

```
(value) => print(value);
```

In dart just `{}` will be treated like the data structure `Set` hence, in this case, you're assigning the function to a Set, hence the error.

Other pointers:-

- You're calling a for loop on the QuerySnapshot which is wrong because you're fetching a single document and not a collection of documents.
- the way you access a key in the latest version of firebase plugin is this way

```
doc.data()['name']
```